# convert a string containing JavaScript object to a JSON string with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, string

This is the javascript Object (just a small part of it):

```
dataToReturn = {
        "dimensionsDisplayType"  : [
            "dropdown","swatch",
        ],
        "pwEnabledDimensionMap" : {

            "size_name": true,

            "color_name": true

        },
        "isPWBadgeEnabled" : true,
        "isImmersiveExperience" : false,
        "isTabletWeb" : false
}
```

So in PHP it will look like:

```
<?php
    $jsObjStr = '{
            "dimensionsDisplayType"  : [
                "dropdown","swatch",
            ],
            "pwEnabledDimensionMap" : {

                "size_name": true,

                "color_name": true

            },
            "isPWBadgeEnabled" : true,
            "isImmersiveExperience" : false,
            "isTabletWeb" : false
    }';
```

But if we would like to parse it with json parse we cant In PHP since its not a clean JSON format because of

```
"dimensionsDisplayType"  : [
            "dropdown","swatch",
        ]
```

The keys containing object like "dimensionsDisplayType" can be unpredictable so cleaning with regex for example wont help much.

The one that works is

```
JSON.stringify(dataToReturn)
```

But in my case I can not run client side code sot it must be converted into the correct JSON format in server side with PHP. I was searching a lot online but I got not any satisfying function or library.

How can this be solved ?

Comment: Where do you get that string from? Did your code produce it, or is it from a third party? Do you have any control over its generation?

Comment: @trincot its from a third party and I dont have any control over its generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try cleaning the string with this regex, this will look for a comma followed by optional whitespace and a close ] and replace this with the content minus the comma...

```
$jsObjStr = preg_replace("/,(\s*?])/", "$1", $jsObjStr);
```